# Problems with login

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I have this code:

[image: website code]

## Enter Username or Email

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("id_username")
elem.send_keys(user)
```

## Enter Password

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("id_password")
elem.send_keys(pwd)
```

## Login

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Autentificare')]")
keyboard.press(Key.enter)
keyboard.release(Key.enter)
```

I can't manage to get this login info sent in order to login on platform

Please help

Thank you

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Autentificare')]")` will return a list, unnecessarily.

Probably you need to find the submit button and press it.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[type='submit']").click()
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[type='submit']").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```